# How to read multi-line cell of csv as one Character in buffered reader

Tags: java

I am using a buffered reader to read CSV file in Java.
In the header row, there are some cells whose header name has been split into multi-line.
When I am trying to read the header first line stops where the cell has a multi-line header name and in the next reading it is showing the second line of the same cell.

I want to read the whole row of the header in one line and then read the second row in the second reading.
[image]

Output of `BufferedReader.readline`:

```
First readline: 予約_4,予約_5,欠陥位置外接四角形左(mm),"欠陥位置外接四  
Second readline: "角形右(mm)","欠陥位置外接四"  
Third readline : "角形上(mm)"
```

In a single cell of the header if the header name is multi-line it is reading in the next line.

Is there any way available in Buffered reader that I can read all lines of single-cell as one character or any other way I can do this?

Comment: Note that there are differenc CSV formats and Excel (which you seem to be using here) uses its own. Newline characters in CSV values are normally escaped so just using BufferedReader won't help much. Better use a proper CSV parser like [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Presumably those header “cells” are either enclosed in quotes or have escaped control characters. `BufferedReader` has no conception of RFC4180 so doesn’t care - it sees a linebreak it breaks the line; exactly like opening your csv in a plain text editor (notepad or whatever). You need to use an actual CSV parser that is aware of the format.

Comment: @BoristheSpider which CSV parser do you think i should use, can you name any?

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic for this site. There are tens of them to choose from. Personally I use the Jackson CSV dataformat if the project is already using Jackson. Otherwise I favour Univocity parsers.